# unable to create a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have created a database registration in MySQL that already has 2 tables users and employees. I want to create a third table `Leave` but it is showing error 1064. I have tried everything. Please guide me what is going wrong.

```
create table leave(
  employeecode int(11) primary key auto_increment,
  description varchar(100) not null,
  fromdate date not null,
  todate date not null,
  status varchar(100) not null
);
```

Comment: Sorry? Unable to understand.

Comment: Still showing the same error

Comment: @aa123 `Leave` is a MySQL keyword. You can't/shouldn't use it as a table/column name. It would be confusing like calling a table or column `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change table name as per below query it will work.

```
create table leavetable( 
employeecode int(11) primary key auto_increment, 
description varchar(100) not null, 
fromdate date not null, 
todate date not null, 
status varchar(100) not null 
);
```

As leave is keyword in mysql used to exit any labeled flow control construct so you can not used keyword as table name.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and a found "leave" is a reserved word in sql, so you can change "leave" with "leave_table"

```
 create table leave_table(
      employeecode int(11) primary key auto_increment,
      description varchar(100) not null,
      fromdate date not null,
      todate date not null,
      status varchar(100) not null
    );
```